# How to convert image in TensorProto in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I have written python client for converting my image in TensorProto which I am sending in the predict request. However, I have a need of writing similar client in Java.

Below is my python code:

```
def run():
    host= "localhost"
    port= "9000"
    request = tensorflow__serving_dot_apis_dot_predict__pb2.PredictRequest()
    channel = setup_channel(host, int(port), None)
    stub = tensorflow__serving_dot_apis_dot_prediction_service__pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel,

    metadata_transformer=create_metadata_transformer())

    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
        image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
        request = tensorflow__serving_dot_apis_dot_predict__pb2.PredictRequest()
        request.model_spec.name = "segmentation-model"
        request.model_spec.version.value = 1
        request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
        tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image))
        response = stub.Predict(request, 200)
```

My input after reading from skimage.io is a numpy array of shape (126,100,3)
I want to achieve the same in java. I have tried to search on internet with no luck so far.

Would really appreciate if someone will be able to help in this.

--------UPDATE---------

Achieved it already.